# Querying table with >1000 columns fails

Tags: questdb

I can create and ingest data into a table with 1100 columns, but when I try to run any kind of query on it, like get all vals:

```sql
select * from iot_agg;
```

It looks like I cannot read it with the following error

```java
io.questdb.cairo.CairoException: [24] Cannot open file: /root/.questdb/db/table/iot_agg.d
        at io.questdb.std.ThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:36)
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
        at io.questdb.cairo.CairoException.instance(CairoException.java:38)
        at io.questdb.cairo.ReadOnlyMemory.of(ReadOnlyMemory.java:135)
        at io.questdb.cairo.ReadOnlyMemory.<init>(ReadOnlyMemory.java:44)
        at io.questdb.cairo.TableReader.reloadColumnAt(TableReader.java:1031)
        at io.questdb.cairo.TableReader.openPartitionColumns(TableReader.java:862)
        at io.questdb.cairo.TableReader.openPartition0(TableReader.java:841)
        at io.questdb.cairo.TableReader.openPartition(TableReader.java:806)
...
```

Comment: Don't have 1100 columns in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Ouroborus might be right in suggesting that the schema could be revisited, but regarding the actual error from Cairo:

**24**: OS error, too many open files

This is dependent on the OS that the instance is running on, and is tied to system-wide or user settings, which can be increased if necessary.

It is relatively common to hit limits like this for multiple different DB engines which handle large amounts of files. This is commonly configured with kernel variables to set the maximum number of open files. Checking the max limit for open files can be done on Linux and MacOS with

```
ulimit -n
```

You can also use `ulimit` to set this to a value you need. If you need to set it to 10,000, for example, you can do this with:

```
ulimit -n 10000
```

**edit:** There is official documentation for capacity planning when deploying QuestDB which takes several factors such as CPU, memory, network capacity, and a combination of these elements into consideration. For more information, see the [capacity planning guide](https://questdb.io/docs/operations/capacity-planning)